# using variables of one function in other function in go lang

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-templates

> ```
>     package main
>
> import (
>    "encoding/json"
>   // "flag"
>     //"fmt"
>     "strconv"
>   "html/template"
>   "time"
>   // "log"
>   "strings"
>   "net/http"
>   "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
>   "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
>   "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
> )
>
>
> type microservice_details struct{
>   Deployment_name string `json:"Deployment_name"`
>   Namespace string        `json:"Namespace"`
>   Image_tag string
>
> }
>
> type namespace_details struct {   
>   Namespace []string 
> }
>
> var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./*.html"))
>
> var label_name string
> var namespace string
> var microservice ="/microservice/"
> var detailed_view="/detailed/"
> var kube_config_path="/home/saivamsi/.kube/config"
>
>
> var config, _ = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kube_config_path)
> var clientset, _ = kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
>
> func main() {
>   templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./*.html"))
>   http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
>       http.Handle("/jpeg/", http.StripPrefix("/jpeg/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
>       http.HandleFunc("/", homepage)
>       http.HandleFunc(microservice, Deployment)
>
>       http.ListenAndServe(":8801",nil)
>
> }
>
> func homepage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
>   namespace,_:=clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces().List(v1.ListOptions{})
>   namespace_tmp := namespace_details{}        
>            for _,s := range namespace.Items{
>              namespace_tmp.Namespace = append(namespace_tmp.Namespace,s.Name)
>            }
>            templates.ExecuteTemplate(w,"homepage2.html",namespace_tmp)
>
> }
>
> func Deployment(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
>
>   name := r.URL.Path[len(microservice):]           
>   var array2  []microservice_details 
>   deploy,_ := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(name).List(v1.ListOptions{})
>         microservice_tmp := microservice_details{}
>       microservice_tmp.Namespace=name
>     for _, d := range deploy.Items {
>      microservice_tmp.Deployment_name =d.Name
>
>      for _, deployment_containers := range d.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers {
> ```
>
> image_tag := deployment_containers.Image[strings.IndexByte(deployment_containers.Image':')+1:]
>             microservice_tmp.Image_tag=image_tag
>             }
>             array2 = append(array2, microservice_tmp)
>                    }
>                    b,_:=json.Marshal(array2)
>                    json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &array2)
>
> ```
>        templates.ExecuteTemplate(w ,"microservices2.html",array2) 
>
> }
> ```
>
> how to use Namespace variable of homepage function in Deployment
>   function.I need to use them inside go templates.
>
> i have to use that Namespace in microservices.html .i tried many
>   things but didnt work.

Comment: If it is a common variable then define it globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go is lexically scoped](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) using blocks. This means any variable declared inside a function `ABC()` will not be accessible from other function `Xyz()`.

If you need such "sharing", you must define `namespace` variable globally of the `homepage`, or pass it by reference`homepage`, and then `deployment`.